# Any fibration of $S^3$ by simple closed curves must have base space $S^2$ and be equivalent to the Hopf-fibration.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

I am currently reading *Great Circle Fibrations of the Three-Sphere* by Gluck and Warner since I am very interested in the Hopf-fibration. In particular I'm looking for properties which make it special, so this caught my eye.

In the introduction, the authors remark that

> Any fibration of $S^3$ by simple closed curves must have base space a two-sphere and, as is well known [S], must be equivalent to the Hopf-fibration.

Sadly, the reference, Steenrod's *The Topology of Fibre Bundles*, isn't available through my university library or any of its partners.

Since this is "well known", I was hoping that someone could perhaps outline a proof, reference a theorem/construct which can be used to prove this fact, or another source in which a proof could be found.

Comment: Does https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764429/is-the-hopf-fibration-the-only-fibration-with-total-space-s3?rq=1 answer your question?